# Trying to use an Esper Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, esper

I am trying to expand on an example from the Esper documentation for the `where` enumeration method, and having issues.  Here is the example in question:

```
select items.where(i => i.location.x = 0 and i.location.y = 0) as zeroloc
from LocationReport
```

What I would like to do seems pretty simple.  Instead of selecting `items` that match this expression :

- I want to select `LocationReport`s that contain at least one `item` that matches the expression.
- Do it over a time_batch window (*emphasized text*non-batched time window is a possibility as well).

So every *n* number of seconds I would receive a collection of `LocationReport`s in which each report contains at least one zero location in its items List.

For Reference, here is the structure of the Java objects used in the Esper example:

> public class LocationReport {   List items;  ...
>
> public class Item {    String assetId; // passenger or luggage asset
>   id    Location location; // (x,y) location     boolean luggage; //
>   true if this item is a luggage piece    String assetIdPassenger; // if
>   the item is luggage, contains passenger associated ...
>
> public class Location {   int x;    int y;  ...

**Background detail** : Assume `LocationReport` is the actual object I am interested in...
  Using EPL like in the example above, the `where` logic works, but the problem is that, in returning only the `items` member, I do not see the `LocationReport` class it came from, which contains other properties besides `items` that my `UpdateListener` needs.

Also, probably not relevant, but in my case, I am receiving a high rate of messages where many LocationReports are duplicates (or close enough to be considered duplicates), and my where clause will need to make that determination and only forward "new" messages.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add some testable code (that reproduces the issue). Mention expected result vs current result, then someone can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the "*" to the select and that gives you the event objects alongside. `select *, items.where(...) from LocationReport`
You could add "output every N seconds" to output. Add "#time(...)" for the time window.